# CS50 IDE: printf returns extra characters

Tags: c, string, cs50

I am having problems with the printf function in the CS50 IDE. When I am using printf to print out a string (salt in this code), extra characters are being output that were not present in the original argument (argv).

Posted below is my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // ensuring that only 1 command-line argument is inputted
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    char salt[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        char c = argv[1][i];
        salt[i] = c;
    } 

    printf("the first 2 characters of the argument is %s\n", salt);

}
```

Comment: C strings must be _null-terminated_, but yours isn't.

Comment: Show us _the original argument (argv)._

Comment: `printf("the first 2 characters of the argument is %s\n", salt);` --> `printf("the first 2 characters of the argument is %.2s\n", salt);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a string terminator in `salt`.

Somehow the computer needs to know where your string ends in memory. It does so by reading until it encounters a NUL byte, which is a byte with value zero.

Your array `salt` has exactly 2 bytes of space, and after them, random garbage exists which just happens to be next in memory after your array. Since you don't have a string terminator, the computer will read this garbage as well until it encounters a NUL byte.

All you need to do is include such a byte in your array, like so:

```
char salt[3] = {0};
```

This will make `salt` one byte longer, and the `{0}` is a shorthand for `{0, 0, 0}` which will initialize the contents of the array with all zerores. (Alternatively, you could use `char salt[3];` and later manually set the last byte to zero using `salt[2] = 0;`.)

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. Quick question just for clarity of understanding: why would it be that if I were to do `printf(%s\n, salt)` after initialising `char salt[3] = {0};`, the compiler would understand that the `0` in `salt[2]` would not be the character '0' but the null terminator of the string?

Comment: Because the _character_ `0` would be written `'0'` in this context which is equal to the _value_ `48`. Try `char test[6] = {'1', '0', 49, 48, 1, 0}; sprintf("%s\n", test);` to see what I mean. (Hint: The smiley has value `1`). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Code_chart

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. In that example however, you did mean `printf("%s\n", test)` and not `sprintf`, right? Correct me if I'm wrong: `sprintf` would require a buffer assigned to it, which wasn't allocated in that example. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `salt` is at least one element shy of being a *string*, unless the `argv[1]` is only one element, it does not contain a null-terminator.

You need to allocate space to hold the null-terminator and actually put one there to be able to use `salt` as *string*, as expected for the argument to `%s` conversion specifier in case of `printf()`.

Otherwise, the string related functions and operations, which essentially rely on the fact that there will be a null terminator to mark the end of the `char` array (i.e., mark the end of valid memory that can be accessed), will try to access past the valid memory which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Once you hit UB, nothing is guaranteed.

So, considering the fact that you want to use

> *"....the first 2 characters of the argument....."*

you need to make `salt` a 3-element `char` array, and make sure that `salt[2]` contains a null-terminator, like `'\0'`.